# How come OSM doesn't like (or offer) bulk downloading of tiles?

Tags: openstreetmap

On one hand they say that their data is completely free, and you are welcome to use it to create your own tiles from it, and they have no problem in you using their tiles for whatever. On the other hand they say that bulk downloading is "strongly discouraged", even though they also point out that maintaining their servers (for delivery) isn't free, and depends on contributors and sponsorships.

So how come it wouldn't be in their interest to let me download all the tiles, and then host them on my own domain? Also, just ball-parking it, how big would that be anyway, if i were to go up to `11` zoom, which seems sufficient for my interest.

Relevant document: https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/

Answer (score 2):

A tile is just on "view" of the underlying open data. It's really just an arbitrary computation based on osm data.
So, even if your "snapshot" of tiles would be only around 10GB or so, these tiles are often not just cached static images but rather have to be (pre)rendered anew, at least every once a time, because the underlying map data is changed. So: it's not about to just provide once a year a 10GB file.

> Heavy use of OSM tiles adversely affects people’s ability to edit the map, and is an abuse of the individual donations and sponsorship which provide hardware and bandwidth.

However, OSM provides all necessary data (Software and data) to setup your *own* tile server. I.e. they are completely open.

However, if you lack the time or expertise to do it, you may find other tile map server. Some provide also downloads, e.g. https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/dataset/osm/ .

You may want to look at osm's own stackexchange here: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/43792/can-i-download-osm-tiles-for-offline-use